# How to make sure maven release plugin deploys the jar with dependencies

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin, release-management

How can I make sure that the jar with dependencies that is created using the maven assembly plugin gets deployed using the maven release plugin? The other issue is only the snapshot version of the jar with dependencies gets created

Answer (score 1):

This is caused probably by using *assembly:assembly* goal instead of *assembly:single* in your pom.xml file. *assembly* is deprecated since some time, you can check it here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: assembly:single is not deprecated, according to your link.

Comment: I mean assembly:assembly, not assembly:single. I have updated the answer.